# Flex/AIR calling Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flex3, air

I have problem with calling javascript function from my AIR / Flex App. In web App this is easy with externallInterface, but in native app it is a problem. My AIR app is similar like this ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
initialize="init()" ... >


<mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[   

      private function init():void
            {
              myHTML.addEventListener(Event.HTML_DOM_INITIALIZE,DOMInit);
                myHTML.location="myAIRHTML.html";

            }

            private function DOMInit(e:Event):void{
                myHTML.htmlLoader.window.inputFunction = testInputFunction;             
            }
      private function testInputFunction(so:String):void{
      //some code    ......
      }

      public function someFunction(e:AIREvent):void{
                myHTML.htmlLoader.window.outputFunction(e.param);
            }

          _]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:HTML id="myHTML" width="5" height="5" visible="true" />

</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

myAIRHTML.html is

```
<html>      
    <head>
        <script language="Javascript">


            var interface = {};     

            function outputFunction(param){     
                var childInterface = document.getElementById("mySandbox").childSandboxBridge;

                childInterface.remoteFunction(param);
            }


            interface.inputFunction = function(someData){
                testInputFunction(someData);
            }                                  
            function initBridge(){
               document.getElementById("mySandbox").parentSandboxBridge = interface;
      }
        </script>
    </head>     
    <body>         
        <iframe id="mySandbox"
            src="js.html" 
            sandboxRoot="http://remote.example.com/js/" 
            documentRoot="app:/myAIRSandbox/"
      ondominitialize="initBridge()">
        </iframe>
     </body> 
</html>
```

and js.html is

```
<html>          
 <head>
     <script language="Javascript" src="http://www/otherexample.com/other.js"></script>

       <script language="Javascript" >

             var interface = {};

             interface.remoteFunction = function(st){  
                alert("st");
                callFunctionInOtherJS(st);
             }


             window.childSandboxBridge = interface;                    

             var someObject = {};

             someObject.SomeFunction = function(someParam){
                window.parentSandboxBridge.inputFunction(someParam);   
             }  

       </script>
  </head>   

    <body ></body>
</html>
```

This throw  "TypeError: Undefined value" when I call "remoteFunction" in myAIRHTML.html. It something important what I missed? Can anyone help? It something important what I forget about documentRoot - I don't use this name on other place ..... Thanks for all replies

Answer (score 0):

it seems a bit confused to me anyway if i've understand this is your error:

If you define this

```
myHTML.htmlLoader.window.inputFunction = testInputFunction;
```

You js in myAIRHTML.html can't call testInputFunction(someData); but inputFunction(someData) because you passed your AS3 function testInputFunction to a variable called inputFunction

Hope this helps